# ¿Como puedo modificar el texto que tiene el login de administracion en strapi?

Tags: javascript, cms, strapi

quiero cambiar el "Welcome to Strapi!" y colocar otro texto, como tendría que hacerlo soy un poco nuevo con strapi, pero me gustaría personalizarlo a mi gusto, el logo tipo si lo pude cambiar a mi antojo, siguiendo la documentación pero el texto de abajo también quiero cambiarlo pero no se como, alguna idea o consejo que deba seguir?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, haz el [tour] para entender como funciona Stackoverflow y el apartado [ask] para tener las pautas necesarias para que tu pregunta capte la atención y sea respondida. También proporciona un [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho o errores que tienes y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen).

Answer (score 1):

Pude resolverlo, en el foro de strapi también tenían la misma duda y se pudo solucionar, modificando el app.js de la carpeta src quedando de esta manera

```
import favicon_icon from './extensions/logoMrw.png';
import favicon_mrw from "./extensions/favicon.png";
import favicon from './extensions/favicon.png';

const config = {
  head:{
    favicon: favicon
  },
  menu: {
    logo: favicon_icon
  },
  auth: {
    logo: favicon_mrw
  },
  theme: {
    colors: {
      primary100: '#E8EAF2',
      primary200: '#E8EAF2',
      primary500: '#ac73e6',
      primary600: '#050E31',
      primary700: '#050E31',
      danger700: '#b72b1a'
    },
  },
  translations: {
    en: {
      'Auth.form.welcome.subtitle': 'Texto que se desea colocar',
      'Auth.form.welcome.title': 'Texto que se desea colocar'
    },
    es: {
      'Auth.form.welcome.subtitle': 'Texto que se desea colocar',
      'Auth.form.welcome.title': 'Texto que se desea colocar'
    }
  },
  tutorials: false,
  Notification: { release: false }
}

const bootstrap = (app) => {
  document.title = "Texto que se desea colocar"
  console.log(app);
};

export default {
  config,
  bootstrap,
};
```

ya depende del idioma que se este usando en strapi, yo los coloque en español y en ingles por si acaso.